# Load a GeoJSON layer with mixed geometries via QGIS's Python module

Tags: qgis, python, geojson, mongodb

I have been able to connect my collection in MongoDB , write and store the collection to as .json file and  load the GeoJSON file as a layer by QGIS's Python module unless there are mixed geometries. 
However, I have a problem when the collection in MongoDB has more than geometry type. It loads only one geometry to QGIS canvas. But when I drag and drop the file, I can load both geometries. So .json file, that has been created, is fine.

```
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27019)
db = client['pb']
cursor=db.section.find()
feature = QgsFeature()# create layer

os.chdir( "C:\Users\Public" )
feature =[]

for data in cursor:
    geom=(data['geometry'])
    id  = (data['properties'])

    feature.append({"geometry":geom, 'properties':id})

json_str = json.dumps(feature)
final={"type": "FeatureCollection","features":feature}

with open('data_3.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(final, f)

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\Public\data_3.json',"mygeojson","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Any advice on what I could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the geometry type in uri:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\Public\data_3.json|geometrytype=LineString',"mygeojson","ogr")
```

geometrytype can be "Point", "LineString" or "Polygon"

Comment: isn't it possible to load directly layer from mongodb to qgis without dumping the json?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. Maybe there is a plugin that allow the direct connection.